# Cacti Monitoring Tool

Tags: php

I went through these clear instructions - 'http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/install_windows.html' and installed Cacti together with IIS instead of Apache.

Everytime I try to browse http://localhost/index.php, a message states that the page cannot be found and I am sure that PHP is working fine as I've tested it.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

As the manual says:  point your web browser to http://your-server/cacti/

In your case it's http://localhost/cacti/

Comment: cacti is hosted on the same server, therefore i don't think it makes any difference as i am using 'localhost' as the website's name

Comment: What you are missing is the difference between http://localhost/index.php and http://localhost/cacti/index.php

Comment: Sorry, that's the same web address I am trying to access.. http://localhost/cacti/index.php, still without success..

Comment: any updates on this query?  if you didn't understand what happened let me know and i can give you an RDP to logon and configure it yourself, should you wish to..

look forward to your reply, thanks..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not IIS guy. If there is no significant reason to stay with IIS, I would recommend installing Apache. Beside that, the manual is little obsolete, since stable version of PHP is 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I managed to install PRTG and is far better than Cacti at a glance :)

Comment: Cacti was always hard to manage for me, the structure of datas, graphs, data queries, devices, etc. But neverthless - it's so-called industrial standart. Try look at Zabbix, it has very similar funcionality.

Comment: I found PRTG quite understandable, effective and very easy to setup.  I don't think I need to use Zabbix now that I have PRTG that performs according to my requirements.